# Magento Discount ANd Tax Calculation

Tags: magento

[image]

Kindly have a look the image showing the checkout details on my magento store. The subtotal price of 6929.82 is correct - to which a discount of 10% is to be applied. The discount amount of 692.98 is also correct.  However I cannot figure out how in the world could magento calculate the difference of 6929.82 and 692.98 as 6321.94 .
Though I am using a custom theme but I have tried restoring to default theme and the result remains the same which tells that the problem is either in the backend settings or in the core magento files. Further into the calculations - application of 14% tax after discount is calculated correctly and added to the figure.

Can anybody help me out in locating the setting that is leading to this strange behaviour from Magento.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of searching for possible solutions I could not come across any full proof solution to my problem. Modifying the Core Magento files is also something I would not recommend unless and until you are very sure what all areas of your website it will affect.

The solution I have implemented is to set the catalog prices as "excluding tax" in Tax Settings and thereafter manually changing all product prices by deducting the tax applicable on them.

e.g Before Implementing the solution:

**Tax Setting** - *Catalog prices include tax*

**Price of Item** (as entered in product specification)- *100* {subtotal 86 + 14@14% tax}

After Solution

**Tax Setting** - *Catalog prices exclude tax*

**Price of Item** (as entered in product specification)- *86*

After implementing this I found the discount totals and everything was being calculated correctly. Since I had only 400 odd products I did it manually over the week just to be sure. However for larger number of products you can also run a query through phpmyadmin(etc) to change the values directly in the database. Do remember to backup your DB before doing so.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like its a bug. See https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/2900/completely-incorrect-tax-calculation

Try the following solution

```
app/code/local/Mage/Tax/Model/Sales/Total/Quote/Tax.php
```

Line 144

```
 if('cart' == Mage::app()->getRequest()->getControllerName()){
    $address->setGrandTotal($address->getGrandTotal() + $address->getTaxAmount());
    $address->setBaseGrandTotal($address->getBaseGrandTotal() + $address->getBaseTaxAmount());
} // if
```

Comment: I did locate this file in the following location:                app/code/CORE/Mage/Tax/Model/Sales/Total/Quote/Tax.php                                                        Line 142,143 and144 in the file currently says:               $this->_addAmount($address->getExtraTaxAmount());
$this->_addBaseAmount($address->getBaseExtraTaxAmount());
$this->_calculateShippingTax($address, $request);                     Kindly elaborate how to implment the code snippet given by you.

Comment: Put the above mentioned code after $this->_processHiddenTaxes();

Comment: This code snippet does in face takes me a step closer to my solution however after putting this code after $this->_processHiddenTaxes();  I have the tax being applied two times now.  So for a Rs 100 item (taxes included) Subtotal is 87.72 and 12.28 is tax . On a 10% discount - subtotal becomes 87.72 - 8.77 = 78.95 (correct). On this 14 % tax = 11.20 is added. However, the tax added figure is shown to me as Grand total exclusive of taxes to which another 11.20 is added and total now becomes 91.20 as the final price. SO basically the only problem left now is to remove the tax being applied twice

Comment: Can you follow the steps here?
http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/error.php/viewthread/290928/

Comment: Apparently the last comment in the thread above has the same problem as mine. What I can understand is the two snippet lines add the tax just before it is showed in grand total excluding tax. Though tax applied and calculations all turn up correctly however the normal tax adding procedure of magento is applied yet again which creates a problem. Do you think looking into the DIFF files if 1.8 version would help. If yes - what files should I check in the DIFF.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe there is Shipping&handling total is not displayed (amount 85.1). You can check all totals and their value through database, review sales_flat_quote_address table.

Comment: The problem is in fact with the Hidden Taxes as is evident from the table mentioned by you. Could you please help me as to how the hidden tax is actually calculated. I guess there is a problem with my tax settings. If nothing else works I would even opt for disabling the hidden taxes for the time being as this is a major problem.